# Python - How to handle space as a value of a variable without quotes?

Tags: python, string

I have a string `"bitrate:8000"`

I need to convert it to `"-bps 8000"`. Note that the parameter name is changed and so is the delimiter from `':'` to `space`.

Also the delimiters are not fixed always, sometimes I would need to change from `':'` to `'-'` using the same program.

The change rules are supplied as a config file which I am reading through the `ConfigParser` module. Something like:

```
[params]
modify_param_name = bitrate/bps
modify_delimiter = :/' '
value = 8000
```

In my program:

```
orig_param = modify_param_name.split('/')[0]
new_param = modify_param_name.split('/')[1]

orig_delimiter = modify_delimiter.split('/')[0]
new_delimiter = modify_delimiter.split('/')[1]

new_param_string = new_param + new_delimiter + value
```

However, this results in the string as below:

```
-bps' '8000
```

The question is how can I handle spaces without the `' '` quotes?

Comment: you do not need the quotes but you do need `.strip()`

Comment: Specifically, adding to what @Ev.Kounis said, `.strip("'")`, or `.strip('\'')`.

Comment: Thanks but I am not able to strip quotes within a string with .strip(). 

`>>>string = "Save' 'a' 'Tree"`
`>>>string.strip("'")`
`"Save' 'a' 'Tree"`
`>>> string.strip('\'')`
`"Save' 'a' 'Tree"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you're getting the `' '` string is probably related to the way you parse your `modify_delimiter` value.

You're reading that as a string, so that `modify_delimiter == ":/' '"`.

When you're doing:

```
new_delimiter = modify_delimiter.split('/')[1]
```

Essentially `modify_delimiter.split('/')` gives you an array of `[':', "' '"]`.

So when you're doing `new_param_string = new_param + new_delimiter + value`
, you are concatenating together `'bps' + "' '" + '8000'`.

If your `modify_delimiter` contained the string `':/ '`, this would work just fine:

```
>>> new_param_string = new_param + new_delimiter + value
>>> new_param_string
'bps 8000'
```

---

It has been pointed out that you're using `ConfigParser`. Unfortunatelly, I don't see an option for ConfigParser (either in python 2 or 3) to preserve trailing whitespaces - it looks like they're always stripped.

What I can suggest in that case is that you wrap your string in quotes entirely in your config file:

```
[params]
modify_param_name = bitrate/bps
modify_delimiter = ":/ "
```

And in your code, when you initialize `modify_delimiter`, strip the `"` on your own:

```
modify_delimiter = config.get('params', 'modify_delimiter').strip('"')
```

That way the trailing space will get preserved and you should get your desired output.

Comment: The parsing is happening through the ConfigParser module which is kinda weird. Your solution yields this:
`["'1", ':', " '"]`

Comment: I updated my answer with a solution for ConfigParser. It's an ugly one, but it will work for your case.

Comment: I am using your solution for now. Thanks!